# Flask {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }} not returning value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm following one of the many basic Flask tutorials in which the `{{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }}` Jinja2 template call is supposed to return the base root of the application (per Flask docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.script_root)).

I have a *super* basic scripts setup as such:

```
# app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask

# import blueprints
from .views.index import index_blueprint

# create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(index_blueprint)
```

This is my `Blueprint`:

```
# app/views/index.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template

index_blueprint = Blueprint('index_blueprint', __name__)

@index_blueprint.route('/')
def route_index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

And finally, my `index.html` template (which lives in the `template` folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Flask test.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

After rendering, `$SCRIPT_ROOT` should contain the script root, or at least a non-empty string. However, the resultant populated template contains an empty string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var $SCRIPT_ROOT = "";

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Flask test.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Question is why does `{{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }}` return an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Flask's WSGI. In this case Flask does not know about the `SCRIPT_NAME` env variable, because usually it is the HTTP servers' job  to set `SCRIPT_NAME` (and `PATH_INFO` as well).

Flask sets `script_root` attribute using this env var (relevant function from [`Request`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L552) class):

```
@cached_property
def script_root(self):
    """The root path of the script without the trailing slash."""
    raw_path = wsgi_decoding_dance(self.environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME') or '',
                                   self.charset, self.encoding_errors)
    return raw_path.rstrip('/')
```

If you want to set it manually, you can achieve this using a middleware (from [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/)):

```
class AppMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app, script_name=''):
        self.app = app
        self.script_name = script_name

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        script_name = self.script_name
        if self.script_name:
            environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = script_name
            path_info = environ['PATH_INFO']
            if path_info.startswith(script_name):
                environ['PATH_INFO'] = path_info[len(script_name):]

        return self.app(environ, start_response)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = AppMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, '/myapp')
```

After this, `{{ request.script_root }}` will be `/myapp` in your template.

Answer (score -1):

From the real [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/jquery/):

> A simple method would be to add a script tag to our page that sets a global variable to the prefix to the root of the application. Something like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>
```

this work for me, only add this tag without `var =`